# The difference between worldTransform and localTransform in ARKit / ARHitTestResult

Tags: ios, arkit, hittest

I'm trying to place an object in AR in a specific location after performing a hittest, but sometimes its misaligned / rotated incorrectly using a worldTransform. I'm trying to apply the localTransform property to the worldTransform as it seems like that would ensure that no matter which feature point is picked up, I can translate the object to the desired location.

I've tried adding/subtracting the localTransform simd_4 matrix to the worldTransform matrix, but it doesn't seem like its actually doing anything meaningful.

This is how I'm actually applying the transformation:

```swift
world.columns.3[0] += local.columns.3[0]
world.columns.3[1] += local.columns.3[1]
world.columns.3[2] += local.columns.3[2]
world.columns.3.w  = local.columns.3.w
```

I have a custom visualizer for where the hittest should land, and I expect that to be exactly where I tapped, but after applying the offset, it seems to go in a random direction.

Answer (score 0):

The difference between world and local transforms is:
- world transform is the model's position relative to the scene's position
- local transform is the model's position relative it's parent node's position

In your case I suspect you are not adding the node directly as a child of the root node, because the rootNode is the (0,0,0) node within the scene any of its children's transformation matrices should be the same.

In your logic, i'm going to assume you project the touch which is not as accurate as setting an infinite plane as the SCNFloor and then detect the touches on the infinite plane. This will give you a much more accurate location when trying to project the touch into the ARSCN.

I would recommend taking a look at ARKit-SmartHitTest by Maxx Frazer as thats how he implements this functionality and his code is open source.
https://github.com/maxxfrazer/ARKit-SmartHitTest/blob/master/SmartHitTest/SmartHitTest.swift